# How many sets of bank statemens do I need to submit when applying for Standard Visitor visas for a family?

Tags: visas, uk, family, proof-provenance-of-funds

I am planning to apply for a tourist visa for myself and my family. I am doing all of the travel expenses for my family.

Do I need to submit my six months bank statement for each application of my dependants or just submit with mine?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to submit your own bank statements but if there is an income that is apparent from another members bank statement then it would be helpful.

Bank statement alone and bank statement accompanied with an income tax papers are two different things. A bank statement accompanied by an income tax papers would hold a lot more weight.